# Not able to bundle application using react-native start

Tags: android, react-native

I was getting one error :

*Unable to load script.Make sure you are either running a Metro server or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release*

So I have fired this command :

`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`

So that error gone, but Now problem is I am not able to debugging. If I am using react-native start command then also in not bundling.

So main problem is I am not able to bundle application.

Please guide on this point.

Thanks.

I am getting this error.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Points :

1. You can still debug on logcat in android studio or Xcode.
2. `run react-native run-android` in one terminal and `react-native start` in another terminal
3. Please check whether the port is `8081` if not then change it in the dev setting in adb by adding your local pc ip.
4. Delete node modules and try updating your metro bundle.  Then install them. Hope this will work!

#### Sometimes the metro bundle hangs, its common.

Comment: run react-native run-android in one terminal and react-native start in another terminal...I have tried but not working

Comment: whats the issue?

Comment: I am attaching screen shot

Comment: Add IP in your dev setting and change port to 8081. It's because the port and the emulator are not under same port

Comment: Yes I have tried same, but still facing same issue. Should it be any native gradle issue?

Comment: I have deleted node modued, then fired react-native link command. And then I have fired react-native run-android command. Is it ok?

Comment: delete you package lock.json file also